# Paypal CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile 10002 error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to create recurring payment profile using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile method of Paypal API version <strike>54.0</strike> 56.0 in Sandbox mode.
Unfortunately I'm getting 10002 error "You do not have permissions to make this API call".
I've rechecked API credentials for few times and it looks correct. Also other methods of API (ex. DoDirectPayment) works perfectly.

Does anybody faced such a problem? What a solution?

Thank you very much I need your help.

UPD:

The request is performed by Zend_Http_Client. Sending get array like:

```
array (
'USER' => 'user_1324103739_biz_api1.domain.com',
'PWD' => 'DCM6SLXFXLW99RRR',
'SIGNATURE' => 'signature',
'VERSION' => '56.0',
'METHOD' => 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',
'TOKEN' => 'EC-12C13621A5208361W',
'IPADDRESS' => '127.0.0.1',
'USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7',
'AMT' => 100,
'SUBJECT' => 'Silver plan monthly payment',
'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
'EMAIL' => 'user@email.com',
'PROFILESTARTDATE' => '2012-19-01CST3:48:2418',
'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => 1)
```

The request example:

GET /nvp?USER=user_1324103739_biz_api1.domain.com&PWD=DCM6SLXFXLW99RRR&SIGNATURE=signature&VERSION=56.0&METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&TOKEN=EC-12C13621A5208361W&IPADDRESS=127.0.0.1&USER_AGENT=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28X11%3B+Linux+i686%29+AppleWebKit%2F535.7+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F16.0.912.63+Safari%2F535.7&AMT=100&SUBJECT=Silver+plan+monthly+payment&CURRENCYCODE=USD&COUNTRYCODE=US&EMAIL=user%40email.com&PROFILESTARTDATE=2012-19-01CST3%3A48%3A2418&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1
 HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
Connection: close
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Zend_Http_Client

Response example:

TIMESTAMP=2011%2d12%2d19T09%3a55%3a14Z&CORRELATIONID=3fcaa599c0ad0&ACK=Failure&VERSION=56%2e0&BUILD=2230381&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Authentication%2fAuthorization%20Failed&L_LONGMESSAGE0=You%20do%20not%20have%20permissions%20to%20make%20this%20API%20call&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error

Comment: Can you include some code and a copy of the full API request you're sending?

Comment: Post updated. Added get array, request and response listings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUBJECT` is causing this. SUBJECT is meant for third-party API authorization where the value of `SUBJECT` is the email address / secure merchant ID of a third party which authorized you to call the API on their behalf, not as a descriptive text. For that you'll want to use 'DESC'.

I would also suggest removing:
**IPADDRESS** (not part of CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API)
**COUNTRYCODE** (not part of CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API)

Comment: Thank you Robert! Removing SUBJECT param did help.